Need to get script that runs computer name from list and verify in ad for OS information
 getting this error when running script 





Get-ADComputer : Variable: 'computerName' found in expression: $computerName is not defined.
  At line:15 char:20
   + ... mpDetails = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $computerName} -Properti ...
   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
 
    Get-ADComputer : Variable: 'computerName' found in expression: $computerName is not defined.
    At line:15 char:20
+ ... mpDetails = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $computerName} -Properti ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer


    # Specify the path to your Excel file
    $excelFilePath = "C:\Scripts\ADcomputerinfo.xlsx"

    # Load the Excel data (assuming the column header is "ComputerName")
    $excelData = Import-Csv -Path $excelFilePath

    # Initialize an empty array to store results
    $computerInfo = @()

    # Loop through each row in the Excel data
    foreach ($row in $excelData) {`your text`
    $computerName = $row.ComputerName

    # Retrieve computer information from AD
    $compDetails = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $computerName} -Properties OperatingSystem,       OperatingSystemVersion

    # Create a custom object with relevant properties
    $compObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $compDetails.Name
        OS = $compDetails.OperatingSystem
        OSVersion = $compDetails.OperatingSystemVersion
    }

    # Add the custom object to the array
    $computerInfo += $compObject
    }

    # Export the results to a new Excel file
    $outputFilePath = "C:\Scripts\ADComputerInfooutput.xlsx"
    $computerInfo | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation

    Write-Host "Computer information exported to $outputFilePath"


gotta love that chatgpt

You can't use "import-csv" for .xlsx files, it needs to in a csv format.
Go on excel and with export the list as a .csv, or save the document itself as a .csv
AI generated questions/answers aren't allowed on stackoverflow.
Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned
The code posted has a lot of errors.
Low effort response in the interim.
# OSInfo for Computers in .CSV file
    # Import computer info from CSV
    $Computers    = Import-csv "C:\temp\ComputersFromExcel.CSV"
    # Loop through each computername in the "Name" column 
    $computerInfo = Foreach ($computername in $Computers.Name){
        # Get-adcomputer info for $computername. "-Properties *" to return all properties.
        Get-adcomputer $Computername -properties * | Select Name,DNSHostname,OperatingSystemVersion 
    }
    # Export-csv to save to a file. -NoTypeInformation removes unnecessary file info from the start of the csv file.
    $computerInfo | Export-csv "C:\temp\ADComputerInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# Alternative - Export OS info for all computers in AD
    Get-adcomputer -filter * -properties * | Select Name,DNSHostname,OperatingSystemVersion | Export-csv "C:\temp\ADComputerInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation

